# Caller does not get correct value from async method with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, async-await

I am trying to wrap my ajax call around a promise. So when the ajax call is complete the promise gets resolved.

In the following snippet:

```
async function getDetails (data){   
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {      
          $.ajax({
                  url: "/get-details",
                  type:"get",
                  contentType:"application/json",
                  data:{"text":data},
                  success: function(result){
                    resolve(result.response);
                  },
                  error: function(result){
                    reject(result.response);
                  }
          });
      });
    let result = await promise;
    console.log(`result: ${result}`);
    return result;
}

function test() {
    let result = getDetails("query-text");
    console.log(`result in test : ${result}`);
}

test();
```

I get correct value in `result` of `getDetails()`. The `result` in test() is a promise object rather than the expected value.

How should I get the desired value from getDetails in an async manner using Promises?

Comment: `$.ajax` already returns a promise, more details here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: An `async function` like `getDetails` always returns a promise. You get the desired value by waiting for the result, either with `.then` or `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `getDetails(...)` returns a promise, not the parameter passed into the `resolve()` or `reject()` callbacks. Therefore, doing this should work:

```
async function test() {
    let result = await getDetails("query-text");
    console.log(`result in test : ${result}`);
}
```

Alternatively, you can do without an `async` method by simply waiting for the promise to resolve:

```
function test() {
    let p = getDetails("query-text");
    p.then(result => console.log(`result in test : ${result}`));
}
```

---

### Even beter: using the new `fetch()` API

Since you're using ES6, you might want to consider [using the `fetch()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) anyway:

```
async function getDetails (data){   
  let result = await fetch('/get-details').then(resp => resp.json());
  console.log(`result: ${result.response}`);
  return result.response;
}

async function test() {
  let result = await getDetails("query-text");
  console.log(`result in test : ${result}`);
}

test();
```

Comment: Agree with your second solution, I was also just looking at how this all was put together and it seemed just a bit messy. You don't need jQuery anymore nowadays.

Comment: That was quick. I ended up using your second solution since adding async to caller method does not look good. Will use `fetch` if possible.

Comment: If you want to consider using `fetch`, consider [using it correctly](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a function as `async`, it will implicitly return a `Promise` if not explicitly done so. This means your `getDetails` function will always return a `Promise`. Thus, you either need to use a `.then` callback to get your result from `getDetails` or use `await` to "unpack" the result from the promise.

Another thing that you can change in your code is that you do not need to wrap your `ajax` request in a promise:

*[jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)*:

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise...

This means that your ajax request will `resolve` and `reject` for you, and thus allows you to treat the return value like a `Promise`, allowing you to set your promise variable directly equal to your ajax request:

```
async function getDetails(data) {

  let promise = $.ajax({
    url: "/get-details",
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
      "text": data
    }
  });

  let result = await promise;
  console.log(`result: ${result}`);
  return result; // returns a new promise with the return value as the resolve
}

async function test() {
  let result = await getDetails("query-text"); // await to "unpack" the promise returned via your async function "getDetails"
  console.log(`result in test : ${result}`);
}

test();
```

But, as **@Terry** pointed out in his great answer, if you're just using jQuery for sending ajax request, there is really no need (unless you're really worried about browser support). [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) can do the job for you.